# "confidence is the best enemy" - One of my students wrote this. I know it's wrong but I can't come up with the actual saying

Tags: vocabulary

One of my students wrote "confidence is the best enemy". I think he means that you cannot trust yourself too much. He was talking about walking in the mountain. He wanted to say that we have to be extremely careful. Is there an actual saying/sentence about this?

Comment: Normally confidence is considered a positive trait but without **context** (what was the topic?)  it's difficult to know what your student meant. I suppose it's related to the [tall poppy syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tall_poppy_syndrome)

Comment: I would ask the student what it means.

Comment: He was talking about hiking in the mountain. He meant that you can't be cautious enough.

Comment: The student probably meant to say "confidence is the worst ally". P.S You should add the context in the question so you get the best answers and not just wild guesses.

Comment: Welcome! You've clarified by adding comments, but please edit the question itself to tell about the student's meaning. Comments aren't as permanent or official as the question itself. The bit you added in the comment is necessary to make this question clear enough to answer.

Comment: He might have meant something like, ["Overconfidence is one's greatest enemy."](https://www.fool.com/investing/general/2013/07/16/fighting-investors-greatest-enemy-overconfidence.aspx)

Comment: The only major issue I see in your student’s comment is the phrase “best enemy.” In the context of his writing, it seems he’s saying that confidence (specifically, overconfidence) is something to be *avoided*, so it doesn’t make sense to use “best” to modify that.

Answer (score 1):

Pride comes/goes before a fall

Comment: No explanation as to why this fits, no reference or link to support the answer. No upvote from me :(.

Comment: As this proverb is from the Bible, and the most common/well-referenced version of the Bible is the King James Version, I almost invariantly see it rendered as "pride *goeth* before a fall."

Comment: Honestly, I wasn’t familiar with the rules of this website and I didn’t know that I should write my answer as a suggestion in the comment to see whether it was suitable for that person or not, bytheway, I wanted to help that person— like myself—that sometimes people may need only a certain and succinct response though. I got one’s idea, because in our language we have the similar phrase, as Iranian people are so metaphorical and I’d got what he/she meant ;)